# Why is my Pitch Object sounds different from my original audio file in PRAAT?

Tags: audio, voice, speech, pitch, praat

So when I extracted visible pitch contour from my original mono stereo audio file, a new Pitch object is created from said file. when i played the Pitch object it sounded different than the original file. Can anyone please elaborate what is pitch contour exactly, does it only capture dynamic intonations?

Answer (score 0):

The pitch object carries a lot of information, but when you press `View & Edit`, and press the bar at the bottom to play the sounds, it resynthesizes a hum, so it's not playing the sound, but a synthesized hum that represents the pitch contour of the original sound.